# TypeError: Member "toTimestamp" is not available in contract DateTime outside of storage

Tags: solidity, remix

I'm implementing a function and I'm getting an unexplained bug from the compiler

```
function _incrementMonths(uint16 _months, uint _timestamp) internal returns (uint){
    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
    uint16 year = dateTime.getYear(_timestamp);
    uint16 month = dateTime.getMonth(_timestamp);

    uint16 newMonth = month + _months;
    while(newMonth > 12){
        newMonth -= 12;
        year++;
    }

    // get new timestamp
    return dateTime.toTimestamp(
        year,
        newMonth,
        dateTime.getDay(_timestamp),
        dateTime.getHour(_timestamp),
        dateTime.getMinute(_timestamp),
        dateTime.getSecond(_timestamp)
    );
}
```

This function gives the following error

```
browser/Payroll.sol:327:16: TypeError: Member "toTimestamp" is not available in contract DateTime outside of storage.
        return dateTime.toTimestamp(
               ^------------------^
```

The contract I'm referencing is found here: https://github.com/pipermerriam/ethereum-datetime/blob/master/contracts/DateTime.sol . The method I'm calling is found here https://github.com/pipermerriam/ethereum-datetime/blob/master/contracts/DateTime.sol#L165

I've been trying to debug this, but I don't see what is causing this error. What is the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the solution given for [No matching declaration found after argument-dependent lookup](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27662/no-matching-declaration-found-after-argument-dependent-lookup?noredirect=1&lq=1), my problem was due to incorrect typecasting of the month variable. I had typecast the month as `uint16` when it should have been `uint8`, thanks to [piper-merriam](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/28/piper-merriam) for pointing out my folly.

Changing the function to as shown below resolved the issue:

```
function _incrementMonths(uint8 _months, uint _timestamp) internal returns (uint){
    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
    uint16 year = dateTime.getYear(_timestamp);
    uint8 month = dateTime.getMonth(_timestamp);

    uint8 newMonth = month + _months;
    while(newMonth > 12){
        newMonth -= 12;
        year++;
    }

    // get new timestamp
    return dateTime.toTimestamp(
        year,
        newMonth,
        dateTime.getDay(_timestamp),
        dateTime.getHour(_timestamp),
        dateTime.getMinute(_timestamp),
        dateTime.getSecond(_timestamp)
    );
}
```