# How to use require() with stings

Tags: contract-development, dapp-development, require, assert, function-pointer

I am trying to run this code on remix IDE:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Aa {

    string public result;    

    function feedData(string _result) public {
        require(_result = "e" , "error");
        _result = result;
    }
}
```

I keep getting an error: **No matching declaration found after argument-dependent lookup.
        require(_result = "e" , "error");**

I looked up the error on stackexchange but the answer doesn't solve this issue. ([No matching declaration found after argument-dependent lookup](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27662/no-matching-declaration-found-after-argument-dependent-lookup?rq=1))

When I change the line:

```
require(_result = "e" , "error");
```

to => :

```
require(_result == "e" , "error"); // adding an extra equal sign.
```

I get the error:
 ***Operator == not compatible with types string memory and literal_string "e"
        require(_result == "e" , "error")***

So now my question is: How can I use require() with a string variable or is there a better way to achieve what the code is trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in equality test for strings (or other arrays), so a common technique is to compare the hashes of the strings instead:

```
function feedData(string _result) public {
    // Compare hashes
    require(keccak256(bytes(_result)) == keccak256("e"), "error");

    result = _result; // This line was backwards
}
```